# GraphQl Count Aggregate entries

Tags: angular, sqlite, graphql, apollo

I am attempting to use GraphQl to count the number of entries in a table, I have an issue with the resolver and I am at a loss.  When I log rows[0] the count is valid, but I am unable to access it when using graphiql, entries is null.
[image]

My type:

```
const TableCount = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Count",
    fields: {
        entries: { type: graphql.GraphQLInt }
       
    }
});
```

My Query:

```
var queryType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
        tableCount:{
            type: TableCount,
            resolve: (source, args)=>{
                return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                    database.all("Select COUNT(*) from projects", function(err, rows){
                        if(err){
                            reject(err)
                        }resolve(rows[0])
                        console.log(rows[0])
                        
                    })
                })
            }
        },
```

Comment: tableCount was returning an object of [{"Count(*)": 17}]. Accessing the "Count(*)" property corrected the problem

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I realized my error for anyone who may be making the same mistakes following the same tutorial.
Resolove needed to be as such

```
resolve({
   entries: rows[0]["COUNT(*)"]
})
```

Comment: Is it a **SQL** query?